# Is using a robotic operating system still considered bare-metal C?

Tags: ros, c

I want to get experience with low-level, bare-metal programming and am not sure if a project that uses an ROS counts as that.

Comment: research Forth programming language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bare metal programming is defined by not using any abstractions that might be provided by an OS and working directly with the hardware. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine) [Technopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3745/bare-metal-programming).

ROS provides an even higher level framework which builds on top of your computer OS, such as Linux, or Windows.

You can learn a lot about low level concepts while using frameworks such as ROS. And you likely will find that you may want to select a specific part of a larger system to implement at the lowest level. A good learning project could be to reimplement an existing piece of functionality in bare metal instead of trying to recreate the entire system at the lowest level.

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, using an ROS is not bare metal programming because you need to be using a computer OS to use it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I second @Tully's statement that Bare Metal is defined as "without the OS in ROS".

Should you use an OS depends on the size of the processor. An 8 bit [μC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf)? Bare metal C. The ROM space is so little that you don't need the abstractions of C++ let alone that of an OS.

An [ARM](https://www.arm.com/products/silicon-ip-cpu/cortex-m/cortex-m33)? Linux takes up only 3MB RAM to run.

An even more capable platform? An OS won't suffice, a plethora of third-party user-space utilities will also be needed as to utilize the platform's capacity.